Gitlab + nginx reverse proxy: Changing external_url breaks Gitlab
while I've managed to set up a reverse proxy forwarding HTTPS requests to gitlab (e.g. https://gitlab.foo.com ), it is still necessary to set the 'correct' external_url in Gitlab's settings.
The issue: When putting an https:// URL in the config, gitlab automatically activates some settings that make the instance break. What settings must one set for gitlab to just take the new external URL and leave it at that ?

Found it, finally.
my Gitlab's listen_port didn't correspond to the one I was using in my docker container running gitlab, (however gitlab was aware of that one). So while having this in docker:
$ docker ps --filter "name=gitlab"
gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest   0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp, :::8088->8088/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2424->22/tcp, :::2424->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4434->443/tcp, :::4434->443/tcp   gitlab

these are the settings that got it working for me:
external_url 'https://<myUrl>' // my HTTPS url with SSL handled by reverse proxy
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2022 // fortwarded by reverse proxy
gitlab_rails['gitlab_ssh_host'] = 'ssh.<myUrl>' // fortwarded by reverse proxy
nginx['listen_port'] = 8088 // the port from docker
nginx['listen_https'] = false // disable SSH

A quick $ docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-ctl reconfigure and everything ran smoothly.
